# Linux perf: is it possible to somehow ignore busy waiting threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, perf

Im trying to do some performance analysis of my process.  The process has many threads that are busy looping / busy waiting for events.  It looks like perf is picking up the busy loops as the top offenders ( as expected ) but is there any sort of magic to somehow have perf ignore these no-op spins?

Comment: Are you in control of the code?

Answer (score 0):

`perf report` can filter by symbol or DSO, but there is no way to use a blacklist.

I thought there might be a way using combining `-p -x`, but POSIX regex don't seem to support negative lookahead, so a blacklist also seems unfeasible.

At the end of the day, you probably want something called *root cause analysis* or *blame shifting* to attribute the waiting time to whatever cause the event itself to be delayed. I don't think this is possible with `perf` directly.

Also it is often better to passively wait for an event rather than busy waiting.